# React Router: Call component function on RouteHandler ref

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to call a component function on a child component RouteHandler.

```
var Bar = React.createClass({
  baz: function() {
    console.log('something');
  },
  render: function() {
    return <div />;
  },
});

var Foo = React.createClass({
  baz: function() {
    this.refs['REF'].baz();
  },
  render: function() {
    return <RouteHandler ref="REF" />;
  },
);
```

Where `RouteHandler` is a `Bar` but `this.refs['REF'].baz` is `undefined`.

See https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/expose-component-functions.html for more information on component functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe react-router currently supports exposing component functions on RouteHandlers and the current hacky workaround is to do:

```
this.refs['REF'].refs['__routeHandler__'].baz();
```

See https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/1597